Spring Security Context Support in Virtual Thread
does any body know how to fix authentication issue Token token = SpringSecurityContext.getToken(); when called in async method
2024-05-08T16:27:17.92+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/1] OUT {"msg":"Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void com.sap.dvh.messaging.EnterpriseMessagingHelper.createVehicleEvent(com.sap.dvh.dto.CreateDVHVehicleRequestDTO,com.sap.dvh.pojo.VehicleInfo) throws com.sap.dvh.exceptions.ServiceInstanceNotFoundException,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException,com.sap.dvh.exceptions.JMSProcessingException","level":"ERROR","written_ts":"1715165837925103120","logger":"org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler","exception_type":"org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException","written_at":"2024-05-08T10:57:17.924Z","thread":"","type":"log","exception_message":"Access forbidden: not authenticated","stacktrace":["org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access forbidden: not authenticated","\tat com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.token.SpringSecurityContext.getToken(SpringSecurityContext.java:36)","\tat com.sap.dvh.messaging.EnterpriseMessagingConfiguration.initializeEMSConfiguration(EnterpriseMessagingConfigur...:27)","\tat com.sap.dvh.messaging.EnterpriseMessagingHelper.createVehicleEvent(EnterpriseMessagingHelper.java:74)","\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unkno

The issue comes after adding this code to enable virtual thread
@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor() {
return new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
}

@Bean
public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
return protocolHandler -> protocolHandler.setExecutor(
Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
}

after trying this as well , its not working
@Bean(TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.APPLICATION_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)
  public AsyncTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor() {
    return new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
  }

 @Bean
  public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?> protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
    return protocolHandler -> protocolHandler.setExecutor(
        Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
  }


Remove the code you have and simply add spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true to your configuration. Which will enable virtual threads, at least if you have a proper version of Spring BOot. If you haven't upgrade else virtual thread support/optimizations haven't been build in yet.

What version of spring-boot are you using and are you certain that the exception you are facing is post the introduction/update to move towards making use of virtual threads in your application?

I'm using below version

com.sap.sgs
security-patched-spring-boot-starter
3.2.5-sap-03

Earlier my application.java had this
@Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
@Override
public DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
executor.setCorePoolSize(30);
executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread-");
executor.initialize();
return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);

}

@amritsingh spring-boot seems to be wrapped around a custom implementation, so you might have to share relevant code, and the exception message(stacktrace) in your post is partial to understanding the cause. Do follow this thread too for a relevant doubt over the integration.

Is this 3.2.5-sap-03 artefact publicly available? I wasn't able to reach it (@Naman, were you?)  Amrit, could you explain what this SpringSecurityContext is doing (or post relevant code in a text of your question or point to its source code)? If it calls Spring's SecurityContext.getAuthentication(), then it won't be available for the arbitrarily spawned thread (see also an SO thread Naman pointed out to). Does this work for non-virtual, platform threads, say, if you use Executors.newCachedThreadPool or a kind instead of newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor?

Nope @igor.zh, had asked for the relevant code and complete stacktrace in my previous comment. I also believe OP is hinting towards the configuration to have been working alright with non-virtual threads.
Amrit, do edit the question and add relevant information in-place.
